# I can't make a GRUB config

Tags: grub2, void-linux, grub2-mkconfig, lts

A few weeks ago, I accidentally updated my kernel, and out of nowhere I got these strange pixelated lines all over my screen. So, I decided to try and use the linux-lts kernel. But, when I tried to chroot into my root directory run 
`grub-mkconfig /dev/sda`
I got 
`/usr/bin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?)`
I am running 32 bit Void.

Comment: Why are you using `chroot`?  Are you trying to do this from a recovery disk/live CD, or the system itself?

Comment: Generally speaking, before chrooting into a dir, mount bind /dev and /sys and mount -t proc the /proc. See the archlinux wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/chroot

Answer (score 1):

Before you chroot into your root partition ("chroot /mnt/sysimage/" for example), you need to mount some system directories first.

```
mount --bind /proc /mnt/sysimage/proc
mount --bind /dev /mnt/sysimage/dev
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sysimage/sys
mount --bind /run /mnt/sysimage/run
```

Then `chroot /mnt/sysimage`, regenerate grub.cfg and initramfs.

Answer (score 0):

The old kernels can be found in the grub menu after the new Void entry. If old kernels are removed with xbps-remove before testing the new kernel then the chroot can be used to boot the installation from a live void usb drive or other rescue disk. The instructions for a chroot can be found in the Void wiki:

[chroot install](https://wiki.voidlinux.org/Category:Installation)

Lessons learned: The vkpurge command will keep an older kernel by default permitting recovery from a failed kernel installation.